# Keras sequential model not training (Stuck on the same Accuracy and Loss)

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to build a classification algorithm for the UCI Tic-Tac-Toe Dataset (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Tic-Tac-Toe+Endgame) and I'm having some problems

```
Model = Sequential()
Model.add(Dense(9))
Model.add(Dense(64))
Model.add(Dense(64))
Model.add(Dense(1, activation="softmax"))

Model.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = "Adam", metrics = ["accuracy"])
Model.fit(X_Train, Y_Train, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, epochs = EPOCHS, validation_data = (X_Val, Y_Val))
```

I get this message for all of my Epochs

```
Epoch 100/100
861/861 [==============================] - 0s 40us/step - loss: 5.3782 - accuracy: 0.6492 - 
val_loss: 4.7916 - val_accuracy: 0.6875
```

Does anyone know a way to fix this

Comment: How is a model with 1 neuron as output trained with binary crossentropy? You have 2 classes (win/lose), you need 2 output neurons if you want to use the softmax & binary crossentropy (and you'll need to one-hot encode your labels)

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your input and output data?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use softmax with one neuron, if its binary classification you should use `sigmoid` activation at the output layer:

```
Model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```